# Make the text "Post has been deleted" popup brighter on a deleted post in Dark Mode

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, design, dark-mode

Earlier, I went to flag a spam post, but it got deleted just before I clicked.  I saw this popup:

[image]

The text and background is just terrible.  Can we please make that *much* brighter (I couldn't make an example because it was deleted)?

Comment: Strange; it is not *that* terrible here.

Comment: I am not kidding you, and what you have posted looks indeed terrible; what I am just saying is that, in my case (machine/browser/you name it), it does not look like that, and I can clearly see the message.

Comment: @desertnaut Ah.  It was like trying to see squid ink at night for me.

Comment: When I see the message on a deleted post it's readable too, like desertnaut said. Do you perhaps have some sort of screen overlay, like night mode or something that could cause this? Although I wouldn't think a screenshot would take that overlay with it.

Comment: @funie200 Nope.

Comment: It’s barely readable because the error message is within the post content, so it has a reduced opacity. Should the message have full opacity, in your opinion? Then it would need to move out of the post content. But tooltips and popups have the same issue; should the move out, too? There is, however, a different type of error message: an [error notice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w8uOv.png) that appears near the top of the page, e.g. when trying to vote on a deleted post. Would it be better if all inline error messages were replaced by these error notice banners?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have put this on our bug board and will have our designers take a look. Marked as [status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred) instead of [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned) simply because I don't have an ETA yet on when this could get fixed.

**Update**: this has been fixed. The error toasts are dark mode friendly now:

[image]